# HTML5 input: min prevents steps any

Tags: html, validation, input

Can a min /  max value be specified when using `steps="any"` or `steps="0.1"`?

### Testing

When an input of `type="number"` has a `min` value set; `steps="any"` no longer allows decimals.

**This input has a VALID value**

```
<input type="number" value="12.5" steps="any">
```

**This input has an INVALID value**

```
<input type="number" value="12.5" steps="any" min="0">
```

---

[<kbd>Example Fiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/nwcpLfev/1/)

Comment: Interesting find. Maybe it has something to do with divisibility? For example, setting `min="0.5"` and `max="99.5"` makes the second example behave the same as the first in Chrome/Win. Edit: actually, it seems to only consider `min`. So this "works" too:  `min="0.5"` and `max="99"`

Comment: @domdom the problem with that though is it now affects the whole numbers.

Comment: I am sure this used to be allowed. Also the inputs are to represent price so 0 is required.

Comment: Well, turns out we both missed the obvious... :)

Comment: Yep, well  can't get em all.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct attribute name is `step`, not `steps`. The misspelled attribute is ignored, causing the step to be defaulted to 1. So use `step="any"`.

Comment: Damn it! I can't believe we missed that! I was digging through the specs, experimenting with the fiddle and never realized it was a simply typo. Good catch!

Comment: You have eagle eyes, well spotted. Sometimes the smallest mistakes can end the world.